# Make the userpicture a link

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have made it possible for users on my website to upload a post, and to see all the other posts from other users as well. The below code attaches the user, who wrote the post, userpicture.

I wanted it to be a link to that user. My problem is that the below code links to the current user, and not the user which created the post.

Anyone who has some ideas of how to fix this? Thank you!

```
{% if item.sender.userpicture_set.all %}
       {% for item in item.sender.userpicture_set.all %}
            {% if item.active %}
                {% if forloop.first %}
                    {% if forloop.last %}
                         <a href='/members/{{ user.username }}'><img src='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item.image }}' class='img-responsive' id='post-userpicture'/></a>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
            <small><a href='/members/{{ user.username }}'>{{ item.sender }}</a><span style='color: grey;'> {{ item.sent }}</span></small>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: In your models, if you have added a foreignkey field for the user to the post (the uploaded one) model, you could use the context to retrieve the user in your view. You may need your models and view to help you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `item` model, add a field `username`, which stores the `username of the user who made this post`.

Here, it creates a link to the current user, because "user" doesn't have any information about the post. It has information about the current user.

After adding the 'username' field,

```
{% if item.sender.userpicture_set.all %}
       {% for item in item.sender.userpicture_set.all %}
            {% if item.active %}
                {% if forloop.first %}
                     {% if forloop.last %}
                           <a href='/members/{{ item.sender.username }}'><img src='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item.image }}' class='img-responsive' id='post-userpicture'/></a>
                     {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
            <small><a href='/members/{{ item.sender.username }}'>{{ item.sender }}</a><span style='color: grey;'> {{ item.sent }}</span></small>
{% endif %}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have change to `item.sender.username`. This should work.

Comment: This is my post model:
class Posts(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=3000) 
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sent_the_post', null=True, blank=True)
    sent = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    read = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

How would you create that field username, which stores what you stated above?

Comment: A little messy the above but there is post, sender, sent, read and a timestamp.

Comment: I have made the changes. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are referencing the `user` object in your link  as `<a href='/members/{{ user.username }}'>`, the correct url should be something like `<a href='/members/{{ item.sender.username }}'>` but it requires you to have a `ForeignKey` reference to the user in the item model.

Comment: I have this with a foreignkey: sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sent_the_post', null=True, blank=True) - I tried the: <a href='/members/{{ item.user.username }}'> but it did not work :(

Comment: using  `<a href='/members/{{ item.sender.username }}'>` should work